# Regex match between 2 text files

Tags: php, regex, file

'1.txt' contains several lines of urls.
'2.txt' contains several lines of root domains.

I wanted to search for each root domain in '2.txt' if it exist in '1.txt' and print out the whole line in '1.txt' if it matches.

For example.

**'1.txt'**

```
http://somesubdomain.rootdomain1.com/242348788/very-long-text/
http://rootdomain1.com/etetdfgret/
http://rootdomain2.com/value?somevalue
http://rootdomain1.com/value?somevalue
http://rootdomain3.com/value?somevalue2
```

**'2.txt'**

```
rootdomain1.com
```

**It should return**

```
http://somesubdomain.rootdomain1.com/242348788/very-long-text/
http://rootdomain1.com/etetdfgret/
http://rootdomain1.com/value?somevalue
```

I got that working, however if '2.txt' contains several lines it only gets the last line to match vs '1.txt'. From the above example if:

**'2.txt'**

```
rootdomain1.com
rootdomain4.com
```

It won't return anything. (which means there's no match for the last line rootdomain4.com)

Here's what I have so far.

```
  <?php
  $file = '1.txt';

  // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
  $contents = file_get_contents($file);

  $lines = file('2.txt');

  ?>

  <div class="datagrid">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($lines as $line) {
          // escape special characters in the query
          $pattern = preg_quote($line, '/');
          // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
          $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
          // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
          preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
          foreach ($matches as $val) {
            echo "<tr><td>".preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $val[0])."</td></tr>";
          }
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div id="paging"><strong><?php echo "TOTAL: ".count($matches); ?></strong></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to bring the relevant code inline. Otherwise it's difficult for people to follow the proceedings and also likely that once the link goes dead this question will be useless to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove possbile newlines from your pattern:
Also as mentioned above remove the backslash in front of the $

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    // escape special characters in the query
    $pattern = preg_quote($line, '/');

    // remove new lines
    $pattern = str_replace("\n", "", $pattern);

    // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*$/m";

    // search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
    preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $val) {
        echo "<tr><td>".preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $val[0])."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Or use the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES flag for the file function

Comment: Adding FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES to the file function solved the problem. I did try removing the backslash in from of $ from the pattern but it produced the same result as with an escaped $.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the problems is that you escaped the `$`:

```
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
```

Remove that backslash.

Comment: Actually it didn't matter when I tried. Adding FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES to the file function solved the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: My mistake. The double quote removes that level of backslash before using the `$` as a regex. Not sure why that option fixed it though. Might be that without that option, every line's string ended with a \n, and `.` doesn't normally match newlines. Though, in multiline mode it should... so yeah, I'm not sure, sorry.